# Change capstyle for errorbars in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I would like to set the capstyle for the vertical lines of an error bar to 'round'. For example, the following code produces some points with errorbars:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot([1,2,3], [2,3,4], marker='o', linestyle='None')
plt.errorbar([1,2,3], [2,3,4], yerr=[1,1,1], fmt=None, linewidth=3, capsize=0)
plt.xlim([0,4])
plt.show()
```

For normal lines, I can set the cap style in the `rcParams` using this:

```
plt.rcParams['lines.dash_capstyle'] = 'round'
```

and I also found some nice examples how to get round capstyles for ticks:

```
for i in ax.xaxis.get_ticklines(): i._marker._capstyle = 'round'
```

but I am not able to find a similar way for the errorbars.

Answer (score 2):

```
plotline, cap, barlinecols =\
         plt.errorbar([1,2,3], [2,3,4], yerr=[1,1,1], fmt=None, linewidth=3, capsize=0)
```

`plt.errorbar` returns 3 objects. `plotline` and `cap` are `Line2D` objects, which you can then do:

```
plotline.set_capstyle('round')
cap.set_capstyle('round')
```

`barlinecols` is a `LineCollection` object. However, the current version (matplotlib 2.0) does not support changing `capstyle` in `LineCollection` objects (see: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8277). But it looks like this will be implemented in the next version.

Answer (score 1):

To give a working code here to change the capstyle of the vertical errorbar lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plotline, caps, barlinecols =\
         plt.errorbar([1,2,3], [2,3,4], yerr=[1,1,1], linewidth=5, capsize=0)

plt.setp(barlinecols[0], capstyle="round", color="orange")

plt.show()
```

[image]

To instead change the capstyle of the errorbar caps, one would need to use some private attributes,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plotline, caps, barlinecols =\
         plt.errorbar([1,2,3], [2,3,4], yerr=[1,1,1], linewidth=1, capsize=8, capthick=5)

for cap in caps:
    cap._marker._capstyle = "round"

plt.show()
```

[image]